# Creating multidimensional array based on a string

Tags: javascript

So I have a huge text file with over 200 lines of links and titles some links have children and some children have children of their own, each link/title is on a separate line (`\r\n`) and each subset family is indicated by tabs (`\t`).

My question is how can I duplicate the structure of this text file in HTML via JavaScript.

following is a sample of the text file:

```
Home (#/)
User Accounts (#/user-accounts)
1. Types of user accounts (#/user-accounts/1-types-of-user-accounts)
    1.1 Super administrator (#/user-accounts/1-types-of-user-accounts/1.1-super-administrator)
    1.2 Global administrator (#/user-accounts/1-types-of-user-accounts/1.2-global-administrator)
    1.3 Account administrator (#/user-accounts/1-types-of-user-accounts/1.3-account-administrator)
    ...etc
2. Sign in to an existing user account (#/user-accounts/2-sign-in-to-an-existing-user-account)
3. Sign up for a new account (#/user-accounts/3-sign-up-for-a-new-account)
    3.1. Entering User Details (#/user-accounts/3-sign-up-for-a-new-account/3.1-entering-user-details)
    3.2. Selecting User Type (#/user-accounts/3-sign-up-for-a-new-account/3.2-selecting-user-type)
        3.2.1 Selecting Account (#/user-accounts/3-sign-up-for-a-new-account/3.2.1-selecting-account)
        ...etc
```

And here is the code I've tried:

```
import data from './raw';

const loadData = () => {
    // Split the string by 'newline'
    const genSplit = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    let temp = [];
    genSplit.forEach((v, i) => {
        let a = (genSplit[i].match(/\t/g) || []).length;
        if (temp[a] == undefined) {
            temp[a] = [];
        }

        temp[a].push(genSplit[i]);
        if (genSplit[i + 1] !== undefined && (genSplit[i + 1].match(/\t/g) || []).length === 0) {
            a++;
        }
    });
    console.log(temp);
    return temp;
};
```

Now I know this is making an `array`, but I thought I would convert the file into a multidimensional array first then iterate over that and build the DOM elements.

Please let me know if my way of thinking about this is wrong or if there is a better way. Also I couldn't find anything about my problem anywhere on the web or here which leads me to believe my way of thinking about this is not the most practical.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Sample code is in es6, since based on your question, I assume you use es6)*

Given that your text file contains items with multiple levels, a multidimensional array is not a good choice, since you don't want to manually count the total number of dimensions to initialise the array. And multidimensional array is also a waste of resource, too.

A better solution is to create a tree, whose nodes represent lines in the text file.

You can create a class to define node:

```
class Node {
   constructor(id, name, link) {
       this.id = id; // '3.2.1'
       this.name = name; // 'Selecting Account'
       this.link = link; // '#/user-accounts/3-sign-up-for-a-new-account/3.2.1-selecting-account'
   }
}
```

For the tree, you can dig up internet for a convenient way to store tree (e.g. using 1D array to store nodes and 2D array to store parent-child relationship), but there are a lot of npm packages for tree-building, such as [symbol-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/symbol-tree), so you might want to take a look first.

The rest is to modify `loadData()` function to parse and create tree, and another function for tree traversal to build corresponding DOM elements.